# How to define multiple 'individually-mutable' variables in one line, which are initially equal in Python

Tags: python, append

Using Python, I'm trying to define multiple variables in a single line.

```
sq1, sq2, sq3 = ([],)*3
```

This solution works fine until I try to append an integer to an individual variable...

I originally wrote the code as follows:

```
sq1, sq2, sq3 = ([],)*3

sq1.append(2)

print(sq1)
print(sq2)
print(sq3)
```

I assumed the output would be:

```
[2]
[]
[]
```

But instead, it is:

```
[2]
[2]
[2]
```

Is there any way I could make it so appending to 'sq1' does not affect the other variables, or would I have to define each variable separately?

Comment: `([],)*3` This creates three references to the **same** inner list object.